# storing data in firebase by id but ignoring duplicates

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a concept of a `show` for an app that I'm building that looks like this:

```
{"band":"Jimmy Herring And The Invisible Whip","date":"2017-12-08T00:00:00-08:00","numberOfShows":"1 show","venue":"Warfield, S.F.","time":"7pm/8pm","soldOut":false,"pit":false,"multiDay":false,"ages":"a/a","price":"$100"}
```

each `show` has several attributes, including one `band`; several rows of `shows` can be the same `event` if the datetime and venue are the same, but each `show` is its own object.

I want to iterate through an array of `show`s and store bands on firebase in a namespace called `artist`.

This is my code for doing that:

```
        for (const parsedShow of parsedShows) {
            let artistref;
            let artist;
            artistref = this.db.ref(`artist`);
            artist = await artistref.push({ name: parsedShow.band });
        }
```

where the node.js function is getting passed an admin-enabled db connection as `db`

This stores data with a topology like

`artist/{id}/[name: {name}]`

which I assume will work fine if I need to populate an `event` namespace as well that has artist `id`s associated with a given event (and where `id` is auto-generated by firebase).

My question is, how do I prevent writes to my firebase db if a given band name is already in the database? I want to enforce unique bandnames only.

Also, is there a way to incorporate an id to be generated by firebase in a ref? I'd much rather have `artist/name/{name: parsedShow.band, id: <some firebase-generated id>}` if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own generated id referring to https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11